# Laravel passport migration not found

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

I installed laravel passport using command `compser require laravel/passsport`, 
but after this, no new migration was made in `database/migrations` directory.
Why is that?

Comment: did you run php artisan migrate?

Comment: try the `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-migrations` and see if you have new migrations in database/migrations folder

Answer (score 7):

The migration files exist in the Passport package in your vendor directory.

The migrations won't be copied over to your database/migrations folder as they don't need to be since they're registered by the `PassportServiceProvider`.

You should just be able to run `php artisan migrate` and they will be included.

---

If you're using Laravel 5.3 or 5.4 then you will need to register the service provide in your `app/config.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I now understand why those are not added in database/migrations directory! At first I thought I need to add them manually in order for clean installs to be problem-free. but I get it now that a `php artisan migrate` will do all migrations on clean installs.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to modify passport migration or just want it inside your migrations folder you can [publish](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#migration-customization) passport migrations files to your migrations folder using publish command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-migrations
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have PassportServiceProvider registered in config/app.php

```
// config/app.php

Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also delete from migrations table specific migration(s). Running php artisan migrate again should recreate specific migrations only.